# Dealing with multi-line JSON? (And, bonus points, CRLF)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I am trying to create & query an Athena table that is reading JSON files, but it chokes on the newlines.  And to make it more difficult, they're currently windows newlines (CRLF)

Error message:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 2 [character 3 line 1]
```

For readability, our JSON looks like this (one row per file, though we have nested arrays, not included here).

```
{
  "event" : "REQUEST",
  "globalTransactionId" : "8de9e1b8-3ab0-4c3b-8b85-cae4e58257a7",
  "inboundIdentifierValue" : "22",
  "timeStamp" : "2020-03-19T20:36:42.864Z",
  "elapsedTime" : 0
}
```

My create table looks like this, and if I strip out ALL newlines, it works.

I've tried both the openx serde and org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestA(
event string,
globaltransactionid string,
inboundidentifiervalue string,
`timestamp` string,
elapsedtime bigint
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://mybucker/test/'
```

Is there any reasonable way to make this work, or do we have to change the file format?

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with Hive in general; in theory you could fix it by writing your own Serde, but that's not supported by Athena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Athena requires that there is one JSON document per line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html), multiline documents are not supported.

Comment: Yes and no... reading some more, it appears that the Cloudtrail log SerDe can read multi-line JSON... but trying to use that with non-cloudtrail logs just throws errors, at least with my data.

Comment: Yes, the CloudTrail is a special case. CloudTrail logs are not multi-line though, there's just the one line, with a single document containing a `Records` property that in turn contains an array of events. The CloudTrail SerDe unpacks that structure, and is designed for that use case only.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I’d found somewhere else where they mentioned reading multi-line JSON with it, obviously incorrect.