# Athena - reserved words and table that cannot be queried

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm putting JSON data files into S3, and use AWS-Glue to build the table definition. I have about 120 fields per each json "row".  One of the fields is called "timestamp" in lower case. I have 1000s of large files, and would hate to change them all.

Here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/reserved-words.html), I see TIMESTAMP in DDL is a reserved word.  Does that mean I won't be able to read those JSON file from Athena.

I'm getting this error, which lead me to the above being a potential reason.

I clicked the 3 dots to the right of the tablename, and clicked "Preview Table", which built and ran this select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM "relatixcurrdayjson"."table_currday" limit 10;
```

That lead to an error which seems wrong or misleading:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed in queries without FROM clause

This query ran against the "relatixcurrdayjson" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: c448f0ea-5086-4436-9107-2b60dab0f04f.
```

If I click the option that says "Generate Create Table DDL", it builds this line to execute:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_currday;
```

and results in this error:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.NullPointerException

This query ran against the "relatixcurrdayjson" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 6ac5d90f-8d52-4e3e-8f16-cd42e1edcfa3.
```

This is the AWS Glue Log:

[image]

UPDATE #1:

I used Athena a couple of weeks ago with CSV and it worked great.
This time I'm using JSON.

I created a new folder with one file containing the following, ran the Glue Crawler:

```
[
    {"firstName": "Neal",
     "lastName": "Walters",
     "city": "Irving",
     "state", "TX"
     }
     
    {"firstName": "Fred",
     "lastName": "Flintstone",
     "city": "Bedrock",
     "state", "TX"
     }
     
    {"firstName": "Barney",
     "lastName": "Rubble",
     "city": "Stillwater",
     "state", "OK"
     }
     
]
```

and this SQL gives the same error as above:

```
SELECT * FROM "relatixcurrdayjson"."tbeasyeasytest" limit 10;
```

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381706/aws-athena-row-cast-fails-when-key-is-a-reserved-keyword-despite-double-quotes)

Comment: @PhilippJohannis - Thanks, but did you see my update where I created a simple small JSON that had no reserved words?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that. Could you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE "relatixcurrdayjson"."tbeasyeasytest"` and post the DDL Statment?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis That gives similar error: Queries of this type are not supported (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to get Glue crawlers to create tables that don't work in Athena, which is surprising given that it's the primary goal it was designed for.

If the JSON you posted is exactly what you ran your crawler against the problem is that Athena does not support multi-line JSON documents. Your files must have exactly one JSON document per line. See [Dealing with multi-line JSON? (And, bonus points, CRLF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781041/dealing-with-multi-line-json-and-bonus-points-crlf/61854226#61854226), [Multi-line JSON file querying in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466526/multi-line-json-file-querying-in-hive/54507266#54507266), and [Create Table in Athena From Nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841006/create-table-in-athena-from-nested-json/63842920#63842920)

Comment: I see an example in your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841006/create-table-in-athena-from-nested-json/63842920#63842920.  So there should be no [] around the top and bottom of file, thus the file is not technically JSON, right?  Any other parser would choke on that.  Also, cannot use "prettyprint" (example in Python: strResults = json.dumps(results, indent=4))

Comment: Follow-up question - it treated my JSON like CSV now... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502018/athena-glue-parsing-simple-json-but-treats-it-like-a-csv

Comment: Also, if I skip Glue, and define the schema myself, can I use real JSON (with [] at top and bottom), and have it indented.  This page seems to show a regular JSON file not on one line - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/  I do however have about 150 fields in my JSON, so that will be somewhat tedious or will have to write a program...

Comment: I get that it can be a bit confusing when the docs just say "JSON file", but keep in mind that JSON is a data serialisation format, not a file format. The spec doesn't say anything about files. In the Hadoop/Spark/big data ecosystem JSON is always formatted one document per line, because it would be wildly inefficient to do it any other way. You must format your JSON data this way, there is no support in Athena for pretty-printed formatting.