# Athena/Glue - Parsing simple JSON (but treats it like a CSV)

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489928/athena-reserved-words-and-table-that-cannot-be-queried), I built a simple JSON file with one "row" per line.
I'm still in shock, because this is not valid JSON, as it doesn't have square brackets around it.

One data file:

```
{"firstName": "Neal",    "lastName": "Walters", "city": "Irving", "state", "TX"  }
{"firstName": "Fred",    "lastName": "Flintstone",   "city": "Bedrock",  "state", "TX"}
{"firstName": "Barney",  "lastName": "Rubble",   "city": "Stillwater",   "state", "OK"}
```

After running through GLUE, this was my first query, which was quite disappointing.

[image]

Below is the schema that it generated.  From it, we can see that GLUE apparently thought this was a CSV instead of JSON.  I didn't see any option when setting up the Glue crawler that asked what type of a file it was, did I miss that somewhere on some hidden option?

For a simple example like this, I can probably manually fix the schema.  But is GLUE really such a poor parser?  In my real application, I have about 150 fields, so ideally it will generate all the columns for me.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `flattb_testflatjson`(
  `col0` string, 
  `col1` string, 
  `col2` string, 
  `col3` string, 
  `col4` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://relatix/polygonData/history/testflatjson/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='FlatJsonTestForAthena', 
  'areColumnsQuoted'='false', 
  'averageRecordSize'='83', 
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'delimiter'=',', 
  'objectCount'='1', 
  'recordCount'='3', 
  'sizeKey'='255', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: There is issue in json **"state", "TX"** should be like **"state":"TX"** change it for all records. This Error is also in your previous question you've mentioned above.

Comment: Wow, i should have file checked it first! I thought I had created a doc so simple that it couldn't be wrong.

Comment: If you want to Validate your JSON use [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and If you want to visualize your JSON use [Json Stack](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) tools.

Comment: Confirming that Glue built table successfully after fixing data.

Comment: FYI - it doesn't seem to cause issues to leave a comma at the end of each json line/row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glue is terrible in general, but this actually surprised me until I saw the comment by Achyut: your JSON is malformed.

JSON is a data format, not a file format. There is no such thing as a correctly formatted JSON file because the specification doesn't cover that. Tools like Spark, Hadoop, and Athena require JSON data to be in files with one document per line, because that makes it easy to efficiently process the data. Sometimes this is referred to as "JSON stream" (which isn't a great name since we're talking about files), or "line-delimited JSON".

I think you will be better off just creating the table manually. You can find an example to start off from in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json-serde.html

You should also use a proper JSON serialisation library for writing your JSON so that you don't end up with syntax errors like that accidental comma instead of colon.

Comment: I'm confused about this line `Tools like Spark, Hadoop, and Athena require JSON data to be in files with one document per line, because that makes it easy to efficiently process the data.` Is it really required to be in **one document per line** (or is it easy for a user to read JSON file)? can you please provide me some good resources?

Comment: The difference between one document per line or all documents in an array is that in the second scenario you have to read the whole file into memory before you can start processing. In the first scenario you can read one line, process it, read the next line, and so on. It requires enormously less memory.

Comment: I've been working with XML for the last 20 years, and still not convinced that JSON is so wonderful.  But it is popular and trending.  I see your point about efficiency, but seems like JSON would have serialization/deserialization rules for going to and from files.  In Microsoft world, I've used NewtonSoft library, and in Python world the json class with its loads/dumps methods.

Answer (score -1):

May be you want to update the Glue table properties -
especially

```
'classification'='csv',
```

to

```
'classification'='json',
```

Comment: Can't GLUE auto-detect the file type? That was one of my questions that I asked.